# Не работает метод IsAssignableFrom

Tags: c#, .net, плагин

Пытаюсь сделать расширяемое приложение. Ищу dll файлы, пытаюсь найти этим методом классы, реализующие интерфейс `ITranslator`. В другом проекте все работает. В этом - нет. Не могу понять причину.

```
public List<ITranslator> LoadPlugins()
{
    List<ITranslator> pluginList = new List<ITranslator>();
    ITranslator plugin = null;
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(ITranslator).Module.FullyQualifiedName);
    try
    {
        foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(PLUGINS_DIRECTORY, "*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(file);

            foreach (Type t in asm.GetExportedTypes())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(t.Module.FullyQualifiedName);
                if (typeof(ITranslator).IsAssignableFrom(t))
                {
                    plugin = (ITranslator)asm.CreateInstance(t.FullName);
                    pluginList.Add(plugin);
                }
            }
        }
        return pluginList;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Проблема при сканировании директории с плагинами."), "Ошибка при загрузке плагинов");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Должно добавлять в список из плагинов, но не добавляет.

```
D:\OneDrive\VSProjects\Translator\Translator\bin\Debug\ITranslator.dll
D:\OneDrive\VSProjects\Translator\Translator\bin\Debug\Plugins\ITranslator.dll
D:\OneDrive\VSProjects\Translator\Translator\bin\Debug\Plugins\YandexTranslator.dll
```

Comment: GetExportedTypes находит ваши типы? Они должны быть публичными, если что.

Comment: Убедитесь что класс, в котором расположен метод `LoadPlugins()` и классы с плагинами используют одну и туже версию сборки содержащей `ITranslator`. Если ваши плагины и `ITranslator` расположены в рамках одного `Solution` перед тем как проверять корректность метода `LoadPlugins()` рекомендую делать `Rebuild Solution`.

Comment: @Monk да, находит. Тупо не работает метод IsAssignableFrom...

Comment: @sp7 вроде используют одну и ту же версию. Есть ITranslator который получается из основного проекта, и есть ITranslator, который получается из сборки YandexTranslator. Но в другом моем проекте тоже самое, и все в порядке.

Comment: Что значит `Есть ITranslator который получается из основного проекта, и есть ITranslator, который получается из сборки YandexTranslator`, у Вас что два `ITranslator `?

Comment: @sp7 ну да, сверху в после вопроса лог. В моем solution 3 проекта, 1 с интерфейсом (библиотека классов), 1 как бы главный, и 1 с yandexTranslator (библиотека классов).
От главного проекта и от yandexTranslator я ссылаюсь на проект с интерфейсом. Получается 2 ITranslator.

Comment: Подождите, `ITranslator` у вас объявлен в двух сборках или из других сборок просто идет ссылка на него (`ITranslator`)?

Comment: @sp7 просто ссылка на него из двух сборок

Comment: Если `Rebuild Solution`  не помогает, попробуйте еще вместо `IsAssignableFrom()` использовать `typeof(MyType).GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(ITranslator))`

Comment: @sp7 дело в том, что я пытался сделать так, чтобы оно в этот иф все таки зашло, оно заходило, но когда доходило до явного приведения к ITranslator, вылетал CastException. Оно не может привести к этому типу. Я в замешательстве.

Comment: Чудес не бывает, нужно искать причину. Попробуйте использовать для создания объекта `Activator.CreateInstance(myType)`

Comment: @sp7 все равно cast exception...

Comment: Добавьте ваш проект в архив, и выложите на файлообменник, я посмотрю.

Comment: @sp7 [ссылка](https://yadi.sk/d/WW-ZXGBruCwSU)

Comment: Попробуйте вместо неправильного LoadFrom использовать правильный Load.

Comment: Сейчас все Ок ) https://cloud.mail.ru/public/EkrM/nj5x7w6Ah Заменил на `Assembly.LoadFile` по удалял референсы и подключил их заново. Все стало работать.

Comment: @sp7 Спасибо большое! Я уже не знал что делать) Плюс Вам в карму)

Comment: Если все ок, могу оформить в качестве ответа )

Comment: @sp7: LoadFile ужасен. Почему не Load?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что `bin\Debug\ITranslator.dll` и `bin\Debug\Plugins\ITranslator.dll` - это две разные библиотеки, которые содержат разные типы `ITranslator`.

Уберите библиотеку `ITranslator.dll` из папки `Plugins`.

Answer (score -1):

Если использовать `MEF`, то загрузка плагинов будет намного проще:
Класс с плагином нужно пометить:

```
  using System.ComponentModel.Composition;

  [Export(typeof(IPlugin))]
```

А потом грузить там, где вам надо:

```
private static IEnumerable<IPlugin> GetPluginsFrom(string path)
{
  if (Directory.Exists(path))
  {
    try
    {
      var container = new CompositionContainer(new DirectoryCatalog(path));
      return container.GetExportedValues<IPlugin>();
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
      Log.Exception(ex, string.Format("Plugins from {0} cannot be loaded.", path));
    }
  }
  return Enumerable.Empty<IPlugin>();
}
```

Плагины грузятся, как и в вашем случае - в основной домен приложения, выгрузить уже не получится.